# Google Sheet SheetID issue

Tags: google-sheets-api

At work I'm developing an automated way to scrape data from a client's googlesheet to input into our database.

I'm using the Google Sheet API to access the Googlesheet in C#.

I've hit a snag tho, I figured the Googlesheet ID would be static, however it can change apparently.

Does anyone know what exactly generates the SheetID? Or what triggers it changing? I noticed adding additional sheets to the googlesheet could change the ID.

Additionally, is there a sneaky way to, instead of using a sheetid in my code, access the sheetids the service account has access to via some kind of API call for example (there will be only one)? Thus not having to worry about the sheetid changing.

Answer (score 0):

- The method [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate) features a [UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest)
- However, it "Updates properties of the sheet with the specified sheetId", but does not allow you to modify the existing `sheetId`
- On the contrary, `spreadsheets.batchUpdate` [`AddSheetRequest`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addsheetrequest) allows you to specify the `sheetId` of your choice for newly created sheets, this explains your statement

> I noticed adding additional sheets to the googlesheet could change
>   the ID.

- If this helps you somehow: the method [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) returns you information about all sheets present in the spreadsheet, including the `sheetId`, `title` and `index`
- So if you are looking for the `sheetId` of specific sheets, e.g. of a sheet with a certain name, or the first sheet of the speadsheet (`index` `0`) - you need to loop through all the sheets accordingly